# Click date on DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, onclick, datetimepicker

VB2012: Maybe I'm not getting how this control works but what I would like to do is to capture the date on the calendar ONLY when a date is clicked. I then take that date and format it and put it in another control.

Tried the CloseUp event but that fires when the user simply clicks on the form and takes focus away from the DateTimePicker.

Tried the ValueChanged event but that gets fired when the user enters the DateTimePicker or when the user browses for a month or year or when the DateTimePicker closes up without clicking on a date. Also the user could choose the current date and since the value hasnt changed it will not fire.

Is there an event I can use to only capture when a specific day in the calendar is clicked?

```
Private Sub dtpDate1_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpDate1.CloseUp
    lstDates1.Items.Add(dtpDate1.Value.ToString("\x ddMMM").ToUpper)
End Sub

Private Sub dtpDate1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpDate1.ValueChanged
    lstDates1.Items.Add(dtpDate1.Value.ToString("\v ddMMM").ToUpper)
End Sub

Private Sub dtpDate1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpDate1.Enter
    Try
        If IsDate(txtDate1.Text) Then
            dtpDate1.Value = CDate(txtDate1.Text)
        Else
            dtpDate1.Value = DateTime.Now
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox (ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really mean a *specific* date or specifically clicks on a date.  The problem with the latter is that if they see that the date in the text portion is OK with them, then there is no reason to even open it and click on the date selected.  If today is not a valid selection, change the minimum value to something that is

Comment: I don't display the text portion of the control only the arrow that drops the calendar. The app is such that the date value can be empty or null. Any date that is clicked on the calendar is valid. But I need ONLY to capture the day click event.

Comment: There isnt a day click event.  Someone tried making a Nullable DateTimePicker on CodeProject which might work.

Comment: Well try as I could I looked for solutions and couldn't find one. I instead turned to a third party control that seems to have more property and events. I will post that in the op if needed.